# WPF TabControl Databinding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, tabcontrol

I'm trying to build a WPF user interface containing a TabControl, and a TextBlock.

I want to bind these two controls to an underlying collection of instances of the following class:

```
class PageModel
{
  public string Title {get;set;}
  public string TabCaption {get;set;}
  public FrameworkElement TabContent {get;set}
}
```

The tab control should display a tab for each PageModel.

- Each tab's header should display the TabCaption property
- Each tab's content should be the TabContent property.

The TextBlock should display the Title of the currently selected tab.

How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
<TabControl x:Name="_tabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding PageModels}">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding TabCaption}"/>
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding TabContent}"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Title, ElementName=_tabControl}"/>
```

Comment: Awesome solution. One more handy thing is to set the Header Value to {Binding Title} and the Content Value to {Binding .}. This allows you to use just a single viewmodel per page with a Title property for the heading.

Answer (score 8):

I also found another solution to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589802/how-can-i-bind-a-list-collection-to-tabcontrol-headers-in-wpf) using ItemTemplate and ContentTemplate.

Also for any WPF newbies like me, after some headaches and frustration I realized that the collection of page models needs to be an `ObservableCollection<PageModel>` instead of a `List<PageModel>` or any changes to the list will not be reflected by the tabs (i.e. you can't add or remove a tab if it's a list).