# WPF - TabControl binding to TabItem property in an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I have an `ObservableCollection<Item>` and I want to set it as the `ItemsSource` property of a TabControl.  The `Item` class contains a Property `TabItem` that returns a `System.Windows.Controls.TabItem`.  I want the TabControl to display the `TabItem`s from the collection.

(In reality, there are lots of properties on the "Item" class.)

Code:

Item class:

```
public class Item
{
    public Item(TabItem tabItem)
    {
        this.TabItem = tabItem;
    }

    public TabItem TabItem { get; private set; }
}
```

TabControl XAML:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl" />
```

Code behind:

```
this.tabControl.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Item>()
{
    new Item(new TabItem() {Header = "TabItem 1 Header", Content = "TabItem 1 Content"}),
    new Item(new TabItem() {Header = "TabItem 2 Header", Content = "TabItem 2 Content"}),
    new Item(new TabItem() {Header = "TabItem 3 Header", Content = "TabItem 3 Content"}),
    new Item(new TabItem() {Header = "TabItem 4 Header", Content = "TabItem 4 Content"}),
    new Item(new TabItem() {Header = "TabItem 5 Header", Content = "TabItem 5 Content"}),
};
```

I've tried setting the `TabControl`'s `DisplayMemberPath` to "TabItem" but that didn't work.  I've been unable to get `ItemTemplate` and `ContentTemplate` to actually display the `TabItem` (I could bind to the Header and Content of the TabItems respectively, but that's not what I want).

If I were using a `ObservableCollection<TabItem>` and set it to `ItemsSource` it displays the `TabItem`s as you would expect, yet I can't get it to work with this additional step.

What am I doing wrong?  Is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you got rid of the Item class and just added TabItems, your code would work.  By doing it that way however, your limiting what you can do with the styling of the TabItems.

Comment: I mentioned at the end of my question that that does work.  But, I already have the "Item" class that is actually a lot more complex than the one used here, and I need to keep it around.  So, I can't do that.

Comment: Just bind to the item class.  The tabcontrol will automatically add a tabitem for each item in your collection.  then you just have to change the tabitem style to bind the header and content to some property in your item class.

Comment: That's very similar to what I already mentioned I tried in the question using ItemTemplate and ContentTemplate.  Unfortunately, either way, I still lose the changes to the TabItems themselves.  But, I think I'm going to have to do it that way anyways, and just add a workaround to get the changes I need to the TabItems.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use style to set the content. You have ItemContainerStyle which would help as stated here : 
[WPF TabControl Databinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686074/wpf-tabcontrol-databinding)

:)