# Accessing main window properties from its child tabs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol

I want to be able to access public members of my Window from within its TabControl Pages. To do that, I've tried switched from using XAML:

```
    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Name="wizardTabs">
        <TabItem Header="Login">
            <Frame Source="LoginPage.xaml" IsTabStop="False"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

to code-based population of the tabs instead, *during the Loaded event* of the main window:

```
        newFrame = new Frame();
        newFrame.Source = new Uri(@"\LoginPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        newFrame.IsTabStop = false;
        tabItem = new TabItem();
        tabItem.Header = "Login";
        tabItem.Content = newFrame;
        wizardTabs.Items.Add(tabItem);
```

I'm using a Frame in the Tab and loading a XAML Page in the Frame. In this way, I thought that the constructor would be available to me so that I can pass a *this* pointer into the Page class:

```
        LoginPage loginPage = newFrame.Content as LoginPage;
        loginPage.parent = this;
```

but I have discovered that loading XAML requires an empty constructor. Also, **newFrame.Content** is always NULL. I'm thinking it's related to the fact that the XAML hasn't been loaded at this stage, but I can't figure out when that XAML load will be performed, and if it's later, how I can set the "parent" pointer.

Thanks for any suggestions. I'm a newbie WPF coder, so please guide me.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use data binding to access the properties?

Comment: Well it's not related to the data--I'm trying to update a status indicator on the main window when the user clicks a particular list item within the tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution. Instead of using the .Source property, I can use the Navigate() method using an instance of the object directly instead of using a URI. So the code looks like this instead:

```
newFrame = new Frame();
newFrame.Navigate(new LoginPage(this));
newFrame.IsTabStop = false;
tabItem = new TabItem();
tabItem.Header = "Login";
tabItem.Content = newFrame;
wizardTabs.Items.Add(tabItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686074/wpf-tabcontrol-databinding).  You can use Setter Property to bind your frame to the content property:

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Name="wizardTabs" ItemsSource= [YourBinding]>
  <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TabItem">        
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding newFrame}"/>
    </Style>
</TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TabItem Header="Login">
        <Frame Source="LoginPage.xaml" IsTabStop="False"/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```