# How to bind property of the WPF TabItem from MVVM way?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, tabs, infragistics

I want to bind "Header" of the TabItem properties on MVVM way.

I bind the "ItemsSource" property of the "XamTabControl" to a list of view models (`List<MyTabItem>` MyTabItem is a viewmodel too).

Here is the XAML Code

```
<igWindows:XamTabControl 
        Height="198" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="0,54,0,0" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}"
        Name="xamTabControl1"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="651">

       <!-- this is the body of the TabItem template-->
       <igWindows:XamTabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock
                      Text="{Binding Header}" />
           </DataTemplate>
       </igWindows:XamTabControl.ItemTemplate>

      <igWindows:XamTabControl.ContentTemplate>
           <!-- this is the body of the TabItem template-->
           <DataTemplate>
                 <TextBlock
                        Text="{Binding Content}" />
           </DataTemplate>
      </igWindows:XamTabControl.ContentTemplate>
</igWindows:XamTabControl>
```

Here is the view model.

```
private ObservableCollection<TabItem> tabs;
public ObservableCollection<TabItem> Tabs
{
     get
     {
          return tabs;
     }
     set
     {
          tabs = value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged("Tabs");
     }
}
```

To display the tab header, I have inserted a text block inside the ItemTemplate in XamlTabControl. I wanna display the header by using the "Header" property of the TabItemEx property instead of using text block.
And I wanna do this to  "CloseButtonVisibility" property too.

Comment: I found the answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686074/wpf-tabcontrol-databinding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from the `stackoverflow`. Please look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/686102/873979)